# Recursion on Linked List

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a recursive Linked List.
At the moment I simply provide the class with two methods, one for tail insertion and a print.
I don't understand why it doesn't print anything.
I think the main problem is on recInsert(node,key) method who interprets the head node always as NULL.
What I'm doing wrong?

I want to print the sequence `8->7->12->22`

Here's my code:

```
 template<class H>class NodeList{
        private:
            NodeList<H> *prev,*next;
            H* key;

        public:
            NodeList(NodeList<H> *next,H *key){
            this->next = next;
            this->key = new H(*key);
        }

            NodeList<H> *getPrev(){return prev;}
            NodeList<H> *getNext(){return next;}

            void setPrev(NodeList<H> *prev){this->prev = prev;}
            void setNext(NodeList<H> *next){this->next = next;}

            void setKey(H *key){this->key = new H(*key);}
            H *getKey(){return key;}    
    };

    template<class H>class List{
        private:
            NodeList<H> *head;

        public:
            List(){
                head = NULL;
            }

        NodeList<H>* insTail(NodeList<H> *nod,H *key){
            if(nod == NULL){
                 nod = new NodeList<H>(nod,key);
            }
            else{
                nod->setNext(insTail(nod->getNext(),key));
            }
                return nod;
        }

        List<H> *ins(H key){
            insTail(head,&key);
            return this;
        }

        void recPrint(NodeList<H> *head){
            if(head == NULL){
                return;
            }
            else{
                cout<<*head->getKey();
                recPrint(head->getNext());
            }
        }

        void print(){
            recPrint(head);
            cout<<endl;
    }
        };

 int main(){
        List<int> *l = new List<int>();
        l->ins(8)->ins(7)->ins(12)->ins(22);
        l->print();
```

### }

I've resolved adding a control on head node on insTail() method

```
NodeList<H>* insTail(NodeList<H> *nod,H *key){
        if(head == NULL)
            head = new NodeList<H>(NULL,key);
        if(nod == NULL){
             return new NodeList<H>(NULL,key);
        }
        else{
            nod->setNext(insTail(nod->getNext(),key));
            return nod;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Don't use recursive function calls. They don't scale well. Use a loop and a `std::stack` instead.

Comment: Unless this is a learning exercise, you should just use `std::list` (or `std::vector`) and be done already, rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: provide a main function too, write an example along with what you expect as its output and what it actually is printing

Comment: Thanks for all the answers,I've edited the post with the info .Normally I create the list iteratively.It's a learning exercise actually, so I'm not allowed to use std::list or vector.

Comment: Unrelated: No need for a dynamic allocation and the extra management overhead it brings here: `List<int> *l = new List<int>();`. `List<int> l;` will do everything you need. You'll have to replace a bunch of `->` with `.`  since you aren't working with a pointer anymore.

Comment: Unrelated: `NodeList`'s constructor leaves `prev` uninitialized. This may come back to bite you later

Comment: Hint: what happens to `head` in `ins(H key)`?

Comment: Important note: passing a pointer to an object passes the object by reference but the pointer is still passed by value and is a local (Automatic) variable. Changing what this local pointer points at will have no effect on the source. If you want to update a pointer inside a function, pass the pointer by reference.

Comment: Slightly less important note: C++ has no garbage collection. That which you `new` you must also `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there: `head` needs to be assigned the result of insTail:

```
head = insTail(head,&key);
```

Comment: But in this case I provide an head insertion,not tail.
Why my  nod = new NodeList<H>(nod,key) won't work?

Comment: You are assigning `nod` to new. This does not affect `head`. It will remain `nullptr`.

Comment: Right! Many Thanks,I've misinterpreted your comment before.I've resolved adding a control on head node.

Comment: Love you back :)